# Rendering Pixel Noise

Tags: java, rendering, game-engine

I was reading code for Notch’s Level Generation app for his 2D version of minecraft (minicraft) and I was going to see if any of you guys understand or could illustrate how this code works? Its pixel based and I know I need to improve my bit manipulation skills lol.

https://github.com/skeeto/Minicraft/blob/master/src/com/mojang/ld22/level/levelgen/LevelGen.java

Comment: please specify what part of the code you need explanation for

Comment: Well just the sample stuff mainly. I can disect some of it. Is it perlin noise? Or did he come up with this himself

Comment: Well, found out.. its a diamond-square algorithm.